# Adding additional values to property of a PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have three objects created that contain data from a parsed Json file.

```
#Get list of synthetic monitors by name
$executedMonitors = $json.result.data.dimensionMap."dt.entity.synthetic_test.name"
Write-Output $executedMonitors

#Get list of HTTP monitors by name
$httpExecutedMonitors = $json.result.data.dimensionMap."dt.entity.http_check.name"
Write-Output $httpExecutedMonitors

#Get list of synthetic & http monitors values
$Values = @($json.result.data.values)
Log "Values of executed synthetics:  ($Values)"
```

This is where the PASS/FAIL status is set using the $Values object.

```
##Checks "Values" value.  If greater/equal to 1 add property or PASS, else add property FAIL
$condition = '1'
try {
    ForEach ($value in $Values) {
        if ($value -ge $condition) {
            $value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName passFail -NotePropertyValue PASS
        }
        else {
            $value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName passFail -NotePropertyValue FAIL
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Log 'No failures occured'
}
```

At first, I only was using the objects $executedMonitors & $Values and added all the values to a custom ps object, shown below, and then formatted to a HTML table.

```
$i = 0
$report = 
if ($null -ne $executedMonitors) {
    foreach ($executedMonitor in $executedMonitors) {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            Application = $executedMonitor
            Status      = $Values[$i++].passFail
        }
}
}
```

Now, I would like to add the additional values from the $httpExecutedMonitors to the $report object 'Application' property, but am unable to do so without multiple additional values printing to the HTML table.

I have tried to add the additional values to the 'Application' property by creating an array and trying to add a new object:

```
$i = 0
$report =@()
$report += 
if ($null -ne $executedMonitors) {
    foreach ($executedMonitor in $executedMonitors) {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            Application = $executedMonitor
            Status      = $Values[$i++].passFail
        }
}
}

#testing
$report +=
foreach ($httpmonitor in $httpExecutedMonitors) {
   New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Application = $httpmonitor}
}
```

as well as creating two separate psobjects and then trying to combine.

Sample json file that contains objects first created:

```
{
    "totalCount": 168,
    "nextPageKey": null,
    "resolution": "Inf",
    "result": [
        {
            "metricId": "(builtin:synthetic.browser.success:filter(and(or(in(\"dt.entity.synthetic_test\",entitySelector(\"type(synthetic_test),tag(~\"API~\")\"))))):splitBy(\"dt.entity.synthetic_test\"):names:sort(dimension(\"dt.entity.synthetic_test.name\",ascending))):names",
            "dataPointCountRatio": 2.004E-4,
            "dimensionCountRatio": 0.00167,
            "data": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "ADR Timeliness Calculator",
                        "SYNTHETIC_TEST-1E31363E09760539"
                    ],
                    "dimensionMap": {
                        "dt.entity.synthetic_test": "SYNTHETIC_TEST-1E31363E09760539",
                        "dt.entity.synthetic_test.name": "ADR Timeliness Calculator"
                    },
                    "timestamps": [
                        1711512000000
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        2
                    ]
                } 
            ]
        },
        {
            "metricId": "(builtin:synthetic.http.resultStatus:filter(and(or(in(\"dt.entity.http_check\",entitySelector(\"type(http_check),tag(~\"API~\")\"))))):splitBy(\"dt.entity.http_check\"):names:sort(dimension(\"dt.entity.http_check.name\",ascending)):limit(20)):names",
            "dataPointCountRatio": 1.2E-6,
            "dimensionCountRatio": 1.0E-5,
            "data": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "SNAP",
                        "HTTP_CHECK-BD16645521BF003A"
                    ],
                    "dimensionMap": {
                        "dt.entity.http_check.name": "SNAP",
                        "dt.entity.http_check": "HTTP_CHECK-BD16645521BF003A"
                    },
                    "timestamps": [
                        1711512000000
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        1
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample HTML output with failing code attempt:
[image: $executedMonitors]
[image: $HttpExecutedMonitors with multiple spaces]

I am unsure if I need to change how the objects $executedMonitors & $httpExecutedMonitors & $Values are configured with the additional metricID data from the Json or if my pscustomobject can be adjusted.

Comment: I use Add-Member $executedMonitor | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $Name -NotePropertyValue $Value

Comment: Where do you get `.passFail` from? I don't see that property in your current Json

Comment: I have added the PASS/FAIL  code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could simplify your code by using [`PSMemberInfoCollection<T>.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfocollection-1.match?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#system-management-automation-psmemberinfocollection-1-match(system-string)) to get the property value used in `Application` property:

```
$condition = 1

$json.result.data | ForEach-Object {
    $status = 'FAIL'
    if ($_.values[0] -gt $condition) {
        $status = 'PASS'
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Application = $_.dimensionmap.PSObject.Properties.Match('*.name').Value
        Status      = $status
    }
}
```

This assuming that these properties always end with `.name`. From the above would be:

```
Application               Status
-----------               ------
ADR Timeliness Calculator PASS
SNAP                      FAIL
```

And converting this to HTML should work just fine using `ConvertTo-Html`.

Comment: My I suggest using `$Status  = ($_.values[0] -gt $condition) ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL'`? This way there is only one value assignment. Might even put it straight in the PSObject construction, though I'm not sure if would make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get `.PassFail`?
That said:

```
$result=foreach ($Data in $Json.result.data) {

    $Application = ($Data.dimensionMap.'dt.entity.synthetic_test') ? $Data.dimensionMap.'dt.entity.synthetic_test' : $Data.dimensionMap.'dt.entity.http_check.name'
    if ($Application) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Application = $Application
            Status      = $Data.Values[0]
        }
    }
}
$result
```

Comment: I have added the PASS/FAIL  code above.